# PRAW: Unable to set the flair for a submission

Tags: python, reddit, praw

This is my script:

```
r=praw.Reddit(user_agent='test')
r.login('<myusername>','<mypwd>')
sub=r.get_subreddit('india')
post=sub.submit('this is a test','This is a test too.')
post.link_flair_text= 'Non-Political'
post.save()
```

When I query the object, it shows the link flair to be set right, but on the site, the flair is not set. I tried to use:

```
post.set_flair('Non-Political')
```

and I got:

LoginOrScopeRequired: `` submit` requires a logged in session or the OAuth2 scope `submit `` requires a logged in session

How do I set the flair for my submission?

From the documentation:

Requires the modflair oauth scope or user/password authentication as a mod of the subreddit.

This makes no sense. Why should one be a moderator to flair his own submission?

Comment: Did you login? https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.16/pages/oauth.html

The error message is quite clear on that.

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry that was a more recent error message. The actual error message when I run the code is:

ModeratorOrScopeRequired: ```set_flair` requires a moderator of the subreddit or the OAuth2 scope `modflair`` requires a moderator of the subreddit` requires a logged in session

Comment: Are you a moderator of the subreddit...?

Comment: No. I am not. But why should I be the mod to set the link flair to my own submission?

Comment: I can't help you here. But have you looked at this? https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.16/pages/code_overview.html?highlight=flair#praw.objects.Submission.set_flair

It says something about populating both the subreddit and item parameters.

Comment: Not sure what it means. Thanks anyway. I guess my bot is dead in the water!