# Flairing a post with PRAW

Tags: python, praw

I'm working with PRAW, a Python Reddit API client. I'm trying to submit a post to a subreddit that requires flairs. This is my code so far:

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("test")
subreddit.submit(random.choice(p),selftext=random.choice(pc))
```

However, after trying to submit...

```
praw.exceptions.RedditAPIException: SUBMIT_VALIDATION_FLAIR_REQUIRED: 'Your post must contain post flair.' on field 'flair'
```

After adding a flair value:

```
subreddit.submit(random.choice(p),selftext=random.choice(pc),flair="other")
```

```
TypeError: submit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flair'
```

How can I add a flair to my post? (only related post I could find [is this outdated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128453/praw-unable-to-set-the-flair-for-a-submission))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.submit

Use either `flair_id` or `flair_text` depending on template's `flair_text_editable` value.